# Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext. io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2HeadersEncoder

Tags: java, firebase, maven

When I Launch my plugin I had this error :
It's a Java plugin build with Maven for spigot (With link to firestore).

```
 [Channel<1>: (firestore.googleapis.com:443)] Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext. Panic!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2HeadersEncoder.<init>(Lio/netty/handler/codec/http2/Http2HeadersEncoder$SensitivityDetector;ZII)V
        at io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.newHandler(NettyClientHandler.java:155) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport.start(NettyClientTransport.java:221) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:34) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:34) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:259) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.access$400(InternalSubchannel.java:66) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$2.run(InternalSubchannel.java:201) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:94) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:126) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onResult(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1886) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.RetryingNameResolver$RetryingListener.onResult(RetryingNameResolver.java:98) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:333) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
```

I'm with Maven (My pom.xml :) :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>ren.yololaxe.rbfirebaseauth.main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>papermc-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Dépendance pour gRPC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.60.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.60.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Alpha1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dépendance pour Guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version> <!-- Utilisez la version compatible -->
        </dependency>


        <!-- Dépendance pour Firebase Admin SDK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0</version> <!-- Utilisez la version compatible -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dépendance pour Paper API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.destroystokyo.paper</groupId>
            <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I did'nt find anything who help, I'm begginer on dev of Java and Firestore

I tried to modify version of different dependencies and delete some but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

grpc-java 1.6 depends on netty 4 ( check here -> https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/releases), but you also import netty 5 in your project. maybe someplace incompatible